# Error runtime can't find classes java3D simpleUniverse lib at netbeans on MacOSX 10.9.5

Tags: java, netbeans, java-3d

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse
at com.jbatik.modules.corak.component.CorakViewElement.init(CorakViewElement.java:140)
at com.jbatik.modules.corak.component.CorakViewElement.<init>(CorakViewElement.java:109)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.netbeans.core.spi.multiview.MultiViewFactory$MapMVD.createElement(MultiViewFactory.java:447)
```

Please help me, i very confuse for installing java3d on MacOSX, before i using Windows 8.1 is good no problem. I have copy the j3dutil,j3dcore,vecmath,jogl, and gluegen-rt on jre/lib/ext  and nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Java3D 1.6.0, I wrote a very detailed tutorial about it, please follow my instructions [here](http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/).

You should NEVER copy any library into jre/lib/ext in order to avoid breaking applets and applications that might use a different version of Java3D or JOGL.